# How can we export jsp to doc file?

Tags: jsp, doc

How can we export jsp to doc file using content type?

Comment: Please do not repost the same question over and over. This is already the third: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945350/open-jsp-into-doc-format and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946032/export-jsp-to-doc-fomat. If you can't find your question back, login the site and click the username link in top nav bar and you'll be able to see your questions in your user profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/261707/sanju

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content type of a JSP via [`setContentType`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29):

```
response.setContentType("application/msword");
```

You'll want to be sure not to output anything from the JSP other than the data making up the Word document. And you'll want to check that MIME type; [this is my source](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php) for the above, which is for one variant of Word files, but I think there's a more canonical MIME type I'm not finding (using "vnd"). And the type for .docx files is different, [Microsoft says here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that it's (deep breath) `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.

Comment: hi, can u give me any example for this??

Comment: @Sanju: That *is* the example. That's all there is to it. So for instance, if you were reading a Word file from a database, having set the content type as per the above, you'd just dump the file data to the output stream.

Comment: where should  i make this like.. response.setContentType("application/msword");
in jsp page? at top or in body tag??

Comment: @Sanju: *"where should i make this...at top or in body tag??"* If the response is a Word file, there *are* no "tags". There's no HTML at all. It's not an HTML page, it's a Word document. Setting the content type means you're saying "the content of this response is an X" where X could be an HTML file (the default for JSPs), or a plain text file, or an image, or a sound file, or a Word file.