# How can I export jsp to doc file?

Tags: java, jsp, docx

I have to add a Button to a JSP to export the page in Word format (.doc or .docx).
I found [How can we export jsp to doc file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948776/how-can-we-export-jsp-to-doc-file) but the link stackoverflow.com/questions/5946032/export-jsp-to-doc-fomat doesn't work anymore.
Do you have a simple example to solve my task or a working link?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The linked question is different. I assume you want to convert the page (HTML) to a doc, whereas the linked question was about downloading an MS Word file. They're different things.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  What do you mean the link doesn't work anymore?  The clickable link certainly works.  The text link you have does not (that question was deleted, but was a duplicate of the linked question regardless).  Anyway, I'm glad you did some looking into the problem, but this question is broad; can you please provide a [mcve] detailing what you've tried so far, and what is not working with it?

Comment: yes, I must have misconfused that article, my problem respects Kayaman's assumption. 
Basically I started with these two lines 
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-word"); 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + "word.docx"); 
which I found here http://www.quicklyjava.com/export-web-page-to-word/ 
but they don't work (I read the matter could be the new versions of MS-Word.

Answer (score -1):

I found the indication of adding these two lines at the top of JSP, which seems to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/msword; charset=windows-1252" %>
```

Thank you to help me to refine the searching !!